# I am unable to print response for xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, debugging, response

I am unable to print response for below :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>

    <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

    alert("Hello world, part 2!");
    callOtherDomain();          

    });

    function callOtherDomain() {

    var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var uName = "";
    var pWord = "";
    var project = '';
    var domain = '';
    var url = 'https://url';
    invocation.open('GET', url, true, uName, pWord, project, domain);

    invocation.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (4 != invocation.readyState) {
            return;
        }
        if (200 != invocation.status) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(this.responseText);
        console.log(invocation.responseText);
        console.log(invocation);
    };

    invocation.send();
}
```

- I get value for console.log(invocation); as -  [object XMLHttpRequest] and this.responseText prints - undefined.
- When using the same credentials with chrome extension for REST API I can see the response.
- I have tried printing - var xmlResponse = invocation.responseXML; - gives 'null'
- var xmlResponse1 = invocation.responseText; also prints whitespace/blank
- console.log(invocation.status);  - print 200 (which means the call is made successfully)
- I am also getting console.log(invocation.readyState); - as 4.
- Here is the details shown on that network tab [snag.gy/kdcwc.jpg](http://snag.gy/kdcwc.jpg), does is mean the response is received
- var headers = invocation.getAllResponseHeaders();
  alert(headers);
  All the headers are also printing blank/whitespace.

anyone can help please ?

Comment: Look in the Net tab of your developer tools. Check that the request is as you expect. Check that the response is ask you expect.

Comment: @Quentin - can you please elaborate.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @Quentin - Here is the details shown on that network tab http://snag.gy/kdcwc.jpg , does is mean the response is received ?

Comment: It means you've got *a* response. Examine the details of it to see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: @Quentin - but invocation.responseXML and invocation.responseText print no details

Comment: It's possible that the response had a body with no content in it. Use the tools in the Net tab to examine it.

Comment: @xyzsfdc: You need to look into the prototype of open function first.

Comment: @Quentin - response shows me the html content of the page from which the request is sent. Is this possible ? Even in that case it should print when i use invocation.responseXML or invocation.responseText

Comment: @xyzsfdc — Then either you are looking at the wrong entry in the Net tab, or you have found an extra problem (getting HTML content wouldn't explain why `responseText` was blank)